# Crear botón Reproducir/Pausa AVPlayer

Tags: ios, swift

He creado un botón que al presionarlo se comienza a reproducir un audio. He intentado pero no he conseguido editar esta función de forma que cuando se empiece a reproducir, el texto del botón cambie a `Pausar` y su imagen también lo haga a la equivalente y al presionar pause el audio y así sucesivamente. ¿Cómo puedo hacerlo? Este es mi código:

```
@IBAction func Reproducir(sender: AnyObject) {

    let urlString = "http://...com/marchas/\(pasarid).mp3"
    let url = NSURL(string: urlString)

    avPlayer = AVPlayer(URL: url!)
    avPlayer?.play()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Siguiendo con el ejemplo de la otra pregunta, lo puedes hacer de varias maneras. Configurando las imágenes por código o bien en el `Interface Builder`.
Por código sería tal que así:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var avPlayer: AVPlayer?
    @IBOutlet weak var playPauseButton: UIButton! {
        didSet {
            playPauseButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "playIcon"), forState: .Normal)
            playPauseButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "pauseIcon"), forState: .Selected)
            playPauseButton.setTitle("Play", forState: .Normal)
            playPauseButton.setTitle("Pause", forState: .Selected)
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        let urlString = "http://elpenitente.playcofrade.com/marchas/\(pasarid).mp3"
        let url = NSURL(string: urlString)

        avPlayer = AVPlayer(URL: url!)

    }

    @IBAction func Reproducir(sender: UIButton) {

        if sender.selected {
            avPlayer?.pause()
        } else {
            avPlayer?.play()
        }

        sender.selected = !sender.selected

    }

}
```

Las partes importantes son el momento de configurar las imágenes y textos para cada estado:

```
playPauseButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "playIcon"), forState: .Normal)
playPauseButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "pauseIcon"), forState: .Selected)
playPauseButton.setTitle("Play", forState: .Normal)
playPauseButton.setTitle("Pause", forState: .Selected)
```

Y cuando pulsas el botón que cambias el estado del mismo (ten en cuenta que en la función reproducir he cambiado el tipo del `sender`):

```
sender.selected = !sender.selected
```

En el `if` simplemente se decide si reproducir o pausar en función del estado del botón.

Si lo qusieras hacer en el `Interface Builder`, debes configurar el estado seleccionando la opción correspondiente aquí:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Donde primero seleccionas el estado y después configurar la imagen que quieras para cada estado.

Comment: Muchas gracias pero al ver el código no veo nada relativo al hecho de que el botón al ser pulsado de nuevo pause el audio.

Comment: He actualizado la respuesta con lo que faltaba

Comment: Muchas gracias!!! Mañana cuando lo pruebe te comento si todo va bien